# Installation of Opencv on raspberry pi using Rasbian OS

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I got this error during opencv installation:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_core
/lib/libgbm.so.1: undefined reference to `wayland_buffer_is_drm'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: * [bin/opencv_perf_core] Error 1
make[1]: * [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: * [all] Error 2

can you help me.
```

Comment: you could try to *skip* the perf tests. `cmake -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF`

Comment: May be these tests are vital for my project ,Then there will be a problem if I skip at this stage. is there none another solution

Comment: true. so ignore that idea

Comment: kindly suggest me another solution